# Select and append a single element in a node with D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a dataset, looking like this:

```
    var values = [
      {label: 'Label 1', values: [8, 2, 5, 9, 3, 6]},
      {label: 'Label 2', values: [5, 4, 3, 4, 1, 0]},
      {label: 'Label 3', values: [3, 8, 3, 9, 0, 1]},
      {label: 'Label 4', values: [1, 6, 3, 9, 3, 6]}
    ]
```

I have made a stack bar chart using this data, so now I have 4 areas with a label for each and a set of stacked bars respectively.

I successfully make this code append 4 areas as containers for the rest visuals:

```
    barElement = barsArea
      .selectAll('.bar-element')
      .data(values)
      .enter()
      .append('g')
      .attr({
        class: 'bar-element'
      });
```

But now, first I need to add labels to each area, then stacked bars container, `g` element to each as well.

What I have to do now is this:

```
    barElement.select('text').remove()

    var barLabel = barElement
        .append('text')
        .attr({
          class: 'bar-label'
        })
        .text(function (d, i) {
          return d.label
        })
      ;
```

Which looks not too cool because I have to manually remove them each time I update the chart.
The same story with stacked bars container `g` element. If I just run `.select(g.stacked-bars-container)`, it won't work because there is no such an element on first run.

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14471923/d3-pattern-to-add-an-element-if-missing) it's suggested to do `.select().data().enter().append()` which doesn't seem to work in my case for some reason.

So, the question, is how do I find a single element inside a node and update it when new data comes in, otherwise add this element first then update on first run?

Comment: Maybe I've missed this part, but why do you need to remove the text manually?

Comment: Because if I do append without remove, it will append multiple text elements on each update. I am afraid I am doing it the wrong way and if I did it properly I wouldn't have to do these workarounds.

Comment: But `barElement` would only contain the new data (you're using `.enter()`), no?

Comment: Seems like I need to review the whole code to make it right, will get back as soon as I get a better formulated issue if it's still exists. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I linked this to another post yesterday and I think it applies 100% to yours as well. Enter, Update, Exit is a integral part of updating data.

http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/ It has a really good example to look at.